# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException exception appearing while reading data from xlsx file using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, xmlbeans

Please find below the code.....

```
package sanityTests;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

public class ApachePOI {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File src = new File("C:/Users/Ishan/Desktop/TestData.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);   // To deal with XLSX workbook 
        //HSSFWorkbook wb1 = new HSSFWorkbook(fis1);   // To deal with XLS workbook

        XSSFSheet sheet1 =wb.getSheetAt(0);
        String data0 = sheet1.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println(data0);
        wb.close();
    }
}
```

While running the program I am getting the following issue:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:601)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:174)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:279)
    at sanityTests.ApachePOI.main(ApachePOI.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:62)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setLoadEntityBytesLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:50)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:85)
    ... 10 more
```

If I change the format of the file from xlsx to xls it works fine.Not sure how to resolve the error. I have included all the jars like xml-beans and poi jars. Still getting the error. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided any version numbers for any of your components. However, `XmlOptions.setLoadEntityBytesLimit(int)` was only added in XMLBeans [version 2.6.0](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.6.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html#setLoadEntityBytesLimit(int)) (from August 2012), and will not be present in 2.4.0.

As far as I can tell, POI has used 2.6.0 itself for quite a long time, but somehow an older version of the library has been included in your runtime dependencies, and will need updating.

**To sum up:** include XMLBeans 2.6.0 in your project and POI will work fine.

Comment: Actually POI still tries to stay compatible with earlier versions of XMLBeans, so it should work, but still seems to have been broken in the latest release, see [Bug 59195](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59195). As you said, using version 2.6.0 should solve the issue here.

Comment: Good spot. When I read the changelog I could see 2.3.0 still listed as the minimum, 2.6.0 recommended - but that bug explains the discrepancy.

Comment: Update: I tried to use version 5.3.0 but still having the same issue here...